# Thymeleaf: how to get URL attribute value

Tags: java, spring, templates, thymeleaf

I can't find any solution for getting attribute from URL using Thymeleaf.
For example, for URL:

```
somesite.com/login?error=true
```

I need to get "error" attribute value.
Also I'm using SpringMVC, if it could be helpful.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

After some investigation I found that it was Spring EL issue actually. So complete answer with null checking is:

```html
<div id="errors" th:if="${(param.error != null) and (param.error[0] == 'true')}">
    Input is incorrect
</div>
```

Comment: You saved me a couple of hours mate today :)

Answer (score 7):

Another way of accessing request parameters in thymeleaf is by using `#httpServletRequest` utility object which gives direct access to `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` object.

An example usage with null checking looks like,

```
<div th:text="${#httpServletRequest.getParameter('error')}" 
     th:unless="${#httpServletRequest.getParameter('error') == null}">
    Show some error msg
</div>
```

This is same as doing `request.getParameter("error");` in java.

Source: [Thymeleaf Docs](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html)

Answer (score 2):

I tried this and it's working for me :

```
<div th:if="${param.error !=null}" class="col-xs-12 form-group">
       
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a th:href="@{somesite.com/login(error = ${#httpServletRequest.getParameter('error')}"><a>
```

This may work.