# Spring Boot Security: How do I access ${param.error} without Thymeleaf?

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

In case of login errors with Spring Boot Security: Both ${param.error} and ${param.logout} work with Thymeleaf - but how do I access them with e.g. Velocity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I wasn't aware that $param represents [URL params](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14514011/3890673). So ${param.error} and ${param.logout} are not generated from Spring Security, they are Thymeleaf-specific - meaning: one has to rebuild this for Velocity, they are not available out of the box