# How to get querystring passed value from the url into spring controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, query-string

I want to get the querystrting passing value from the given `url`, like: `http://localhost:8080/app?contentid=10`  I want to get the value of `contentid is: 10` from the above url in my spring controller, how can I get this ?

Please note that if I pass any value there(like 10, 50,100, 200, ...etc - it can be any number), so whatever I am passing to `contentid`, that value should get into my controller. I want to get this `contentid` value from that `url` only, not from my html page or I don't want to pass from my html page. Currently I am getting `null` from the below code in controller, I am not getting the passing value(like 10 from the `url`). How can I achieve this ? Thanks in advance for your help !

app.html:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/app}" th:object="${TestData}" method="post">
             <div class="form-group">
                <label for="firstname">First Name: </label> <input type="text"
                    class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname" ></textarea>
            </div> 
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="secondname">Second Name:</label> <input type="text"
                    class="form-control" id="secondname" name="secondname" />
            </div>  
            <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

TestData.java:

```
public class TestData implements Serializable{
    private String firstname;
    private String secondname;
    private int contentid;

    //setters and getters

    public TestData() {}
     public TestData(String firstname, String secondname, int contentid, ){
     this.firstname = firstname;
     this.secondname = secondname;
     this.contentid = contentid;
     }

     @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format(
                    "TestData[firstname=%s, secondname=%s, contentid=%d]",
                    firstname, secondname, contentid);
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
public class TestDataController {
    @Autowired
   TestService testDataService;
     @RequestMapping(value="/app", method=RequestMethod.POST)
     public String testDataSubmit(@RequestParam(required=false) Integer contentid, @ModelAttribute TestData testData, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
     String id = request.getQueryString();
     System.out.println("My Id: "+id);//null 
     System.out.println("URL Parameter: "+testData.getContentid());//0
     System.out.println("URL Parameter passed objectid: "+contentid); //null
     testDataService.saveTestDataDetails(testData);
      return "app";
         }

    }
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class TestService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void saveTestDataDetails(TestData testData) {
    StoredProcedureQuery sp = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("APP.TESTDATA");
     sp.registerStoredProcedureParameter("firstname", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
     sp.registerStoredProcedureParameter("secondname", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);
     sp.registerStoredProcedureParameter("contentid", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);

     sp.setParameter("firstname", testData.getFirstname());
     sp.setParameter("secondname", testData.getSecondname());
     sp.setParameter("contentid", testData.getContentid());     

    sp.execute();

    }

    }
```

Comment: Please provide an example with working code, e.g. in your second code snippet, there is no variable `userComments2`.

Comment: @DominikSandjaja, sorry I have updated that, its my spelling mistake.

Comment: send the contentid as a request parameter. where is the problem?

Comment: @Patrick, how can i send contentid as a request parameter, may i know please to get that value

Comment: try this: `th:action="@{/app?contentid=10}"`

Comment: @Patrick, i want to pass or get it dynamically, i hope it works for contentid=10, if I give some other value, then it will not work at that time ?

Comment: you can pass your variable instead of the number 10.

Comment: @Patrick, means like this: th:action="@{/app?contentid=contentid"}  ? i am sorry if i am wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164386/discussion-between-patrick-and-guna).

Comment: @Patrick, Could I know please

Comment: I got the solution at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14513662/thymeleaf-how-to-get-url-attribute-value

Answer (score 1):

After discussion per chat I will provide you a working solution where you can specifiy any stuff by your own needs.

app.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4">
<head>

<title></title>

</head>
<body>

<th:block th:if="${contentid != null}">
<div th:text="${'contentId: ' + contentid}"></div>
</th:block>

    <form action="#" th:action="@{/app(contentid=${contentid})}" th:object="${TestData}"
        method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="firstname">First Name: </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname"
                name="firstname" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="secondname">Second Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="secondname"
                name="secondname" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("/app")
    public String getApp(Model model) {
        return "app";
    }

    @PostMapping("/app")
    public String postApp(@RequestParam(required=false) Integer contentid, @ModelAttribute TestData testData, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println(contentid);
        if(contentid == null) {
            contentid = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 100 + 1);
        }
        model.addAttribute("contentid",contentid);
        return "app";
    }

}
```

Comment: getting the error: 
Validation failed for object='testData'. Error count: 1

Answer (score 0):

First change your html code `th:action="@{/app?contentid=10}` and then add setter and getter method for the instance variable in the class TestData.

Comment: it may work work contentid=10, but if i give some other value randomly, then it will not work.